# Order by in parent child hierarchy

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following table which needs to be ordered in parent child hierarchy based on strand...I'm not getting how to order it based on parent id.

```
sid    parent_id    snum  strand         Sname
1       0           3      3.1           civics
2       0           3      3.2          geography
3       0           3      3.3          history
4       1           3      3.1.1        civic and insti
5       1           3      3.1.2        civic and poli
6       2           3      3.2.1        geo poli
7       4           3      3.1.1.1       CIVI
8       4           3      3.1.1.2       CIVVISSSDS
```

I want the table  ordered based on the strand in parent child hierarchy the following way..

```
Strand 
 3.1
 3.1.1
 3.1.1.1
 3.1.1.2
 3.1.2
 3.2
 3.2.1
 3.3
```

STUCK ON it since hours...any idea how to proceed ?

Comment: Show your SQL statement

Comment: I don't know if this will work in MySQL, but in SQL Server just order on strand. Have you tried this already?

Comment: I have used insert statements to retreive the data from 3 different tables into a new 4th destination table which is the above one

Comment: @Kevin - that may work for the trivial sample where all units only take one character to express, but usually for this sort of thing, they want each element to be treated as numeric. Neither mysql nor SQL Server will sort `3.1.10.1` after `3.1.9.1`, without more work. (Instead, they'll place it between `3.1.1.1` and `3.1.2.1`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - indeed, you are correct. I've tested only with the sample data in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
ORDER BY RPAD(trim(strand),50,'.0');
```

http://rextester.com/NIK55090

This way, you are changing `3.1` to `3.1.0.0.0.` so ordering would be correct.
Change `10` to more than your `max(length(strand))`

Comment: my max(length) is 45..i tried 50 but its not coming

Comment: but when i tried to give 5....everything is geting sorted except the first element...3.1 is showing at the end of the list...like after 3.1.3.11

Comment: the same case with 3.2..its showing at last..instead of 1st

Comment: Try adding `trim` as updated in answer. It is working fine for the sample of data you gave.

Answer (score 0):

you could use rpad for order by (adding some char for buil same length string)

```
  select * from your_table
  order by rpad(trim(strand), 64, 'Z')
```

Comment: its showing the same result..ordering aint happening

Comment: use a value for length  >  of max number of chars ...and trim off all the spaces